# Find all devices on network

Tags: windows, networking, configuration, network-programming, arp

I have a switch that requires a configuration file to be transferred to it via TFTP before the switch will operate correctly.  My network operates on a 10.x.x.x IP scheme, but the switch comes from the factory with a 192.168.1.x IP address.  There is a headless embedded system in charge of network management which will change the IP address of the switch to it's proper 10.x.x.x address, then transfer the configuration file to the switch.  My issues is, I don't know how to find the MAC address of the new switch.  Basically, the scenario is as follows.  A switch in my network ceases to operate.  A maintenance worker will swap out the switch.  The network management system will be notified to scan the network for new devices.  When the switch's MAC address is found, the IP address will be changed, then IP based communications can commence to transfer the configuration file.  I'm working in C++ on this project.  Code snippets would be cool, but if someone could just tell me a process for finding this MAC address I would be indescribably grateful.  Thanks!

EDIT:  OS is Windows Embedded 7 Standard

Comment: You should add a tag for the operating system (Linux vs Windows). In Linux, you could probably put the network interface into promiscuous mode, listen to all ARP the packets with something like libpcap, and then manually send an ARP request "who has 192.168.1.x" (the IP of the switch). When you see a reply with libpcap, you'll know the MAC address.